# Selectively Update App in Windows 8.1 Store

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-store, windows-store-app, windows-tabletpc, tablet-pc

I was recently given a new tablet with a fresh instal of Windows 8.1 on it. Naturally, there are apps installed that have newer versions available. Some of these apps will not allow themselves to be used until updating, but when I try to update them I run into some trouble. Clicking update now from within an app, or going into the Microsoft app store to update both land me in the same window showing all apps with available updates selected. There are three buttons, select all, clear and instal.

The problem I have is I cannot select 1 or any combination of apps for updating without selecting all of them. Clear deselects all of them, but I am unable to find the single select functionality. How is this done? Surely Microsoft doesn't expect everyone to blindly update apps without reading the change log or permissions. Long tapping shows a translucent check mark in the upper left corner of the app's icon, but the check mark does not persist.

Comment: Select functionality of what exactly? You either update or don't just like most mobile stores

Comment: I want to select 1 app and update only it and leave my other apps alone; not updated. For comparison, in androids app store I can update Firefox but not update chrome and es file explorer to the latest versions.

Comment: Hmmm, that may have been unclear. By "single select" I simply mean to select 1 app, vs select all.

Comment: Yes; you do it similarly, you simply update the application, you want to update

Comment: Right, I assume there is a way. But I cannot figure out how to do it which is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To single select apps for updating in the windows store follow these steps:

1. On the app update page, all apps are selected for updating by default. Tap 'clear' at the bottom of the screen to deselect all.
2. To single select, long tap an app, then slide down. This seems to be the secret way to single select in the metro interface. Repeat with additional apps to multi select.
3. Tap update to update selected apps.